# System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The wait operation timed out

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I have to read very large data, approximately 300000 lines, from SQL tables and write it to a text file in my application (.net application and using C#). I have a stored procedure to read that data, and I am using `DataAdapter` and `DataSet` in my code to get that data, but I am getting the error

> The wait operation timed out

when it executed `dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet)`. I tried to change value of timeout, but it didn't work. I tried different approaches, but nothing seems to work. It works for few lines, but it doesn't work for large data. I can't grab small data because they need whole data in one text file

Comment: Please provide some of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and very important change I did-- I changed my `DateTime` object to `shortDate` (e.g startDate.ToShortDateString() ), so it deleted the time part from my date, and it helped a lot with my SQL stored procedure with `datetime` param.

2nd change --- read directly from `SqlDataReader` and writing directly to text file with `Read` method, because `DataTable` will not hold to long file (e.g 420000KB)

```
using (SqlDataReader rdr = comm.ExecuteReader())
{                               
   while (rdr.Read())
   {
     file.WriteLine(rdr.GetString(0), true);
   }
}
```

3rd change --I increased my timeout

```
comm.CommandTimeout = 600; ( e.g for 10min)
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for help, my code is working fine now. ;)

Answer (score 0):

See if you can split one query into multiple ones and execute it simultaneously and join the results on completion of all fetches.

Or even using a DataReader will help.

Comment: Thx.I already tried DataReader and its giving me same error. Company doesn't wanted to split query. that's the problem